# Github Pages doesn't show my index.html

Tags: html, github-pages

I just recently bought a porfolio template and try to install it onto github pages. It will only show the background but there will be no images or text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your Github Pages site is hosted over https and your template is including plain text http links to resources. You cannot safely load plain text http resources in a secure https connection. You need to fix the error messages such as:

> Blocked loading mixed active content http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic”

Note the conversion from `http` to `https` in the following links:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lilita+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alegreya+Sans+SC' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And there's another with the jQuery link:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

On a related note, your repository is missing the magnifique popup library. You can replace the URL with a link to a CDN. For example, change this line...

```
<script src="js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
```

to this line...

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir!!! I have been for 2 days trying to find the answer to this!!!

Answer (score 1):

It's loading your `index.html` just fine, the problem is that your webpage is loading resources over insecure http when github defaults to using secure https, this results in mixed content errors so a bunch of other resources are failing to load.